# two questions, second only appearing if you answer 'y'

Tags: bash

I have this as part of a bash script

```
{
    read -n1 -p "Do you want to download some tv programmes? [y/n/q] " ynq ;
    [Yy] read -n200 -p "Please input the tv programme numbers to download " 'tvbox';
        echo; cd /media/$USER/back2/proggies/; /usr/bin/get-iplayer --get $tvbox;
    [Nn]* ) echo;;     # moves on to next question in the script
    [Qq]* ) echo; exit;;            # quits
    * ) echo "Thank you ";;
    esac
};
```

But it fails to work because of syntax errors. How can I get it to ask two questions, the second only appearing if you answer "y" to the first, and then the syntax errors being resolved so that the script works please? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the beginning of the `case` statement, and the first case is missing a parenthesis and its concluding `;;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beginning of your `case` statement appeared to be malformed.

```
{
    read -n1 -p "Do you want to download some tv programmes? [y/n/q] " ynq
    case $ynq in
     [Yy]) read -n200 -p "Please input the tv programme numbers to download " 'tvbox'
           echo
           cd /media/$USER/back2/proggies/
           /usr/bin/get-iplayer --get $tvbox
           ;; 
     [Nn]* ) echo;;     # moves on to next question in the script
     [Qq]* ) echo; exit;;            # quits
         * ) echo "Thank you ";;
    esac
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I've got it working now but had to put in an extra 'echo' after [Yy]) and before 'read -n200'. Thanks for this, its been bugging me for days.